# Is it possible to tile dodecahedrons in a 3D grid without any spaces between them?

Tags: platonic-solids

Is it possible to tile dodecahedrons in a 3D grid without any spaces between them? Feel free to send me web links about that.

Comment: Do you mean tessallate $3$ space with regular dodecahedra ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Have you researched this question? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation#Tessellations_in_higher_dimensions

Answer (score 1):

The dihedral angle of a [regular dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron) is $2\arctan \phi \approx 116.565^\circ$.  As this does not divide into $360^\circ$ evenly, there will be gaps between them.